# joining multiple arrays into a single foreach

Tags: php, laravel

i tried to combine

```
$in = DB::table('in')
->select(DB::raw('SUM(in.qty) as inqty')
->groupby('itemname')
->get;
$out = DB::table('out')
->select(DB::raw('SUM(out.qty) as outqty')
->groupby('itemname')
->get;
```

and the result i wished for is like

```
item name    in   out 
item 1       2    1
item 2       5    3
item 3       4    2
```

but i dont know how to combine foreach so mine was still like

```
item name    in   out 
item 1       2    
item 2       5    
item 3       4     
item 1            1
item 2            3
item 3            2
```

does anyone know how to combine them?

Comment: If your `item` has an id than with the help of `inner join` you get data in a single query instead of using 2 diff query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this loop

```php
$in = DB::table('in')
->select(DB::raw('SUM(in.qty) as inqty')
->groupby('itemname')
->get();

$out = DB::table('out')
->select(DB::raw('SUM(out.qty) as outqty')
->groupby('itemname')
->get();

$output = [];
foreach($in as $key => $row){
    $temp = [
        "item name" => $row['itemname'],
        "in" => $row['inqty'],
        "out" => $out[$key]['outqty'] ?? "",
    ];
    array_push($output,$temp);
}

dd($output);
```